# Kotlin extending to second constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

My current class is below :

```
class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService() {}
```

GCMListenerService is as below

```
public class GcmListenerService extends zzb {}
```

Now i'm looking to extend to another constructor.
When i try to do this ,

```
class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService(), PushDataReceiver {}
```

I get error

> Only one class may appear in supertypelist. This type has a
>   constructor, and thus must be initialized here

The PushDataReceiver is as below

```
public abstract class PushDataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

I've been trying to google

> Kotlin adding secondary constructor

Somehow I'm not able to get any assist for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Java, Kotlin doesn't support multiple inheritance. You can only extend a single class at a time - although you can implement multiple interfaces. If you need both a `GcmListenerService` subclass and a `BroadcastReceiver`, you'll have to create separate classes for them.

---

To explain the error message you're getting:

> Only one class may appear in supertypelist. This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here

This error is pointing out that when you extend a class (unlike when implementing an interface), you need to call its constructor by adding parentheses (and if it has constructor parameters, pass those within these parentheses), like you did with the other class:

```
class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService(), PushDataReceiver() {}
```

But again, since you can only have one direct superclass, this won't work.

Comment: Can i work with this? `open class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService()    {
class extended : PushDataReceiver() {`

Comment: You can, but nesting classes like that doesn't provide you much more than just having completely separate classes for the two. Although if what you want is to access parts of the outer class from the nested one, an [inner class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#inner-classes) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: `class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService(), PushDataReceiver() {}` are you sure this can be compiled?

Comment: "But again, since you can only have one direct superclass, this won't work."